# After Effects CC Audio Playback not working

Tags: after-effects, audio

So I've been having this problem with my After Effects CC recently and it's actually cheesing my right off. I need to edit a frame by frame storyboard animatic and I can't edit to the sound because the sound refuses to playback. I've tried everything, there is no ''RAM PREVIEW'' button in the new version of AE and the period button simply resizes the window now. What do I need to do to make this work?

[image]

[image: Screen grab of the Audio Pannel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that I had to change my Audio Hardware output because my partner was editing a video and using his gaming chair as the output, I was at uni and didn't have it connected up, didn't realise AE has to have its audio output set up manually!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a machine with a number pad, then by default <kbd>num-pad 0</kbd> is the ram preview button. If you're on a laptop with no num-pad, then try <kbd>crtl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

If you look in the `Window` menu you'll find a `Previews` panel that will let you set the keyboard shortcuts and their behaviours. More if you want to [RTFM here](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/previewing.html).

Comment: I have figured it out, but just to note I did all of that anyway. Used ever shortcut there was. Turns out, my speakers were not selected under Audio Hardware outputs....

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the "cache before playback" checkbox.  It is on the right hand side in the first screen shot near the playback controls (in the panel highlighted in blue.)  That looks like it should be the same as RAM preview.

Comment: No clue where that check box is!

Comment: It is right in your screen shot, on the right side in the box that is highlighted in blue.